# How to change previous and next post to page title?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the code I currently have -

```
<div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Newer posts', 'azurebasic' ) ); ?></div>

<div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( 'Older posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'azurebasic' ) ); ?></div>
```

How can I have it show the page title instead of Newer Posts and Older posts?

Comment: _"show the page title"_ - which page title?? The title of the Post maybe?

Comment: also please tell us which framework it is that you are using here

Comment: Sorry, yes.  The blog title instead of "older posts" and "newer posts"

Comment: Is it WordPress? Maybe see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/129905/previous-posts-link-and-next-posts-link-how-to-return-the-next-previous-posts and https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post

Comment: Wordpress - this is in the functions.php file.  Here's a link to the site - http://lucchesipgh.org/word-of-the-week/

Comment: @Jeff - I took a look at your reference, I'm not very advanced in php and don't know how to change what I have to work.  Could you give me an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I found online - "next/previous post link functions have defaults for all their arguments, and the second one will default to '%title', which will be replaced with the post's post_title property."

Here's what I used and it worked!

```
<div class="nav-next"><?php previous_post_link( '%link' ); ?></div>

<div class="nav-previous"><?php next_post_link( '%link' ); ?></div>
```